# What are the benefits of using WCF over ASMX web services?

Tags: wcf, web-services, asmx

What are the benefits of using WCF over ASMX web services?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 13):

What makes WCF powerful is its ability to expose services via [multiple addresses, bindings and contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733107.aspx). In WCF, you're programming at the **interface** level as opposed to the actual operation. If you think about it, this is extremely subtle, yet enormously powerful. With ASMX style services you're restricted to an http endpoint hosted by IIS, where as with WCF you can expose a single contract and **implement** and **host** it in a variety of ways. For example, if you wrote a calculator asmx service that returned the sum of two numbers, it would forever live on IIS and invoked from there. The same service operation, i.e. Add(int a, int b) via WCF could not only be altered in its implementation per channel, but could be hosted in many different ways outside of IIS. Also in ASMX if you're looking to implement any of the WS* Standards, you would have to use WSE etc, WCF wonderfully handles all this lower level plumbing for you, which you can implement via configuration or code, think Secure Conversation, Transactions, etc etc. There are lot of resources on WCF, you can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163674.aspx) for a good starting point

Answer (score 2):

While I did not put this site together, the microsoft site "Champ vs. Contender" provides lots of resources for showing why they feel WCF is the better choice vs. ASMX.

http://www.microsoft.com/net/wcf/champ/

Answer (score 1):

ASMX web services are now considered by Microsoft to be "legacy technology". WCF should be used for all new web service development.

Comment: Can you provide a link to support this statement about ASMX?

Comment: http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%E2%80%9Clegacy-technology%E2%80%9D/

Comment: I think your info is a bit out of date or Microsoft's left hand doesn't know what the right is doing.  The relevant line "XML Web services will continue to be supported for many years and there may be cases where it does not make sense to migrate an existing Web service.":  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649453.aspx

Comment: @matt: how does that contradict why I said, or what Microsoft has said about ASMX being a "legacy technology"? There are cases where it makes no sense to migrate from Classic ASP, which is certainly more of a "legacy technology" than ASMX is. Also, something from P&P about the Web Service Software Factory has little to do with the overall Microsoft strategy about ASMX.